# Shared Preferences not working for storing/receiving data

Tags: android

Here I have a block of code that sends information from the current activity to another one:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.amrapps.paneraautomate", MODE_PRIVATE);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        final CheckBox passwordReveal = (CheckBox) findViewById
                (R.id.checkbox);

        passwordReveal.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                } else {
                    password.setInputType(129);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void continueButton(View v) {
        String stringName = name.getText().toString();
        String stringLastName = lastName.getText().toString();
        String stringPassword = password.getText().toString();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        prefs.edit().putString("name", stringName).commit();
        prefs.edit().putString("lastName", stringLastName).commit();
        prefs.edit().putString("password", stringPassword);
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I am trying to use the data entered there in my MainActivity like so:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);

        name = prefs.getString("name", "");
        lastName = prefs.getString("lastName", "");
        password = prefs.getString("password", "");

        // Check for null values and set default if empty
        if (name == "") {
            name = "Johnny";
        }

        if (lastName == "") {
            lastName = "Appleseed";
        }

        if (password == "") {
            password = "Asdf123";
        }
```

Unfortunately, every time it runs it always sets the name to "Johnny Appleseed" even if the value is not null!

Comment: The first thing is, you are using two different preference files. The next thing is that [you are comparing Strings incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Oh my god you're right! This is super embarrassing because we just learned about this last chapter in my AP Computer Science class... :'(

Answer (score 5):

The `getSharedPreferences("com.amrapps.paneraautomate", MODE_PRIVATE)` and `getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);` should use the same string as the first parameter

Comment: Wow. I feel stupid :P. Also, as a commenter above posted, I was comparing strings incorrectly.